# How to make auto-updating (ajax) counter correctly? Or how to disable network log?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make auto-reload counter (for ex.: Messages [num]).
So, I just in `setTimeout();` getting JSON code from test_ajax.php. I think it's not correctly..

Can I send info by server (I think not, but suddenly I something don't know..)?

Why I think that's not correctly: because when I'm looking in my chrome **network log** (F12 -> network tab), I see a lot of requests (to test_ajax.php), but when, I'm visiting vk.com (great example for ajax) or facebook.com, I don't see any requests while something will not change.

So, what's incorrectly in my solution (or what's bad..)?

UPD: Sorry, vk.com sending requests to q%NUM%.queue.vk.com every 25s, but until 25s last request's status is "Pending". When someone, for example, sending me a message it immediately display it. And request has parameter "wait" which equals 25. This delay in requests doing on server side.. But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called COMET (also sometimes called Reverse AJAX) techniques.

Doing what you want to do, e.g. regular polls, is one way of doing it.

A lot is actually happening on the server side; to avoid recreating new connections on every poll, some servlet containers like Jetty started to implement techniques like Continuation which basically maintain a two-way connection open.

In the Java world, with Servlet 3, you have asynchronous calls as part of the specs.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about it.. But it's  [good, very good](http://youtu.be/tfslY_AvhLw).

Answer (score 1):

Ajax counter can be done in easy just include below files

1. index.html
2. counter.php (ajax file)
3. necessary images
4. JS file (for jquery paging call)

download link: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5dn0M5-kgfDcE0tOVBPMkg2bHc

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please be aware that signing of your answers with your email address is discouraged. If you want to publicise your contact details please edit your [user profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1484843/praburaj) to do this instead.